# Horizontal scrollable TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have TextView that automatically scroll left-to-right when input text doesn't fit into it.
Now I need to add the ability to scroll horizontally through the hands of the text in TextView when the text does not fit into it - so the user can view the contents of TextView.
I add TextView to HorizontalScrollView:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnBackspace"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewLeftIndent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calculateField"
            android:layout_width="534dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="80sp" >

        </TextView>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

But now I have editable through the virtual keyboard TextView and cannot scroll full text, only part of it (when text's big).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your TextView widget

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

and check if it works now

update

It it not works add this

```
android:singleLine=”true”
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. (Why I can't vote up your message?)                    Now I need to make the virtual keyboard does not appear when I click on the TextView, but so that scroll of TextView continued to work properly.

Comment: //TextView calculateField;                 calculateField.setText(result);
horizontalScroll.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);                                                                                                  All the time when I programmatically add text in TextView I scroll TextView to the left calling fullScroll(FOCUS_RIGHT) method, but for some reason the text scrolls not completely - there is one invisible character

Comment: I solved his problem. I changed **android:ellipsize="marquee"** to **android:ellipsize="end"** It remains only to decide how to make when show activity, and when you touch the TextView does not appear on-screen keyboard (ie how to block android' on-screen keyboard)